# How do I get year and month when day is invalid without fixing the day myself?

Tags: r, date

I have some data that looks a bit like this:

```
require(zoo)

X <- rbind(c(date='20111001', fmt='%Y%m%d'),
            c('20111031', '%Y%m%d'),
            c('201110', '%Y%m'),
            c('102011', '%m%Y'),
            c('31/10/2011', '%d/%m/%Y'),
            c('20111000', '%Y%m%d'))
print(X)

#      date       fmt     
# [1,] "20111001" "%Y%m%d"
# [2,] "20111031" "%Y%m%d"
# [3,] "201110"   "%Y%m"  
# [4,] "102011"   "%m%Y"  
# [5,] "31/10/2011" "%d/%m/%Y"
# [6,] "20111000" "%Y%m%d"
```

I only want the year and month.  I don't need the day, so I'm not worried that the final day is invalid.  R, unfortunately, is:

```
mapply(as.yearmon, X[, 'date'], X[, 'fmt'], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# $`20111001`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`20111031`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`201110`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`102011`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`31/10/2011`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`20111000`
# Error in charToDate(x) : 
#   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I know that the usual answer is to fix the day part of the date, e.g. using `paste(x, '01', sep='')`.  I don't think that will work here, because I don't know in advance what the date format will be, and therefore I cannot set the day without converting to some sort of date object first.

Comment: What package is `as.yearmon` in? Code should be reproducible. Also you are coercing integers to character in your example data, so that is not ideal.

Comment: @mdsumner: `as.yearmon` is in the zoo package.

Comment: I know, but it should be in the q - which it now is I see

Comment: You need to be much clearer whether *"get the year and month"* means **as a string, or some date type, or anything at all**? Seems you mean **as some data type (zoo::yearmon, in this case)**. Can you please edit your title to be clear? (I don't know what you want otherwise I'd edit it myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I'm always given a date (and never a time), and that any illegal 'day' is less than 61, I can guarantee a legal date as follows, by treating the supplied day as 'seconds' and replacing the supplied day with the 1st.

```
require(stringr)

safe_date <- str_c('01', X[, 'date'])
safe_fmt <- str_c('%d', str_replace(X[, 'fmt'], '%d', '%S'))

mapply(as.yearmon, safe_date, safe_fmt, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# $`0120111001`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`0120111031`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`01201110`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`01102011`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`0131/10/2011`
# [1] "Oct 2011"

# $`0120111000`
# [1] "Oct 2011"
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the month always follows the year and is always two characters in your `date`. Why not just extract the information with `substr`. Perhaps something like:

```
lapply(X[,'date'], 
  function(x) paste(month.abb[as.numeric(substr(x, 5, 6))], substr(x, 1, 4))
  )
```

Comment: I'm using `as.yearmon(substr(X[,'date'], 1, 6), '%Y%m')` at the moment, but I'd prefer not to assume that the first 6 chars will always be `'%Y%m'`.  I'll change the example data to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify the day in your format if you don't need it.  Read `?strptime` carefully.  The second paragraph in the Details section says:

> Each input string
>        is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any
>        trailing characters are ignored.

So adjust your format and everything should work.

```
X <- rbind(c(date='20111001', fmt='%Y%m'),
           c('20111031', '%Y%m'),
           c('201110',   '%Y%m'),
           c('102011',   '%m%Y'),
           c('20111000', '%Y%m'))
mapply(as.yearmon, X[, 'date'], X[, 'fmt'], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: The format is supplied to me with the date.  I could modify the format I'm given by using `str_replace` from `stringr` to remove/replace `'%d'` from the format string, but that will only work if the day is at the end of the string.